# Max(date) in inner query

Tags: sql, db2

I was given sample SQL which does not seem to do what I need.

Big table has 4 million rows and small table has 600 thousand rows.

/* Sample code: (I was given this sample by a senior analyst) */

```
SELECT SUM(BigTable.VALUE)
        FROM BigTable INNER JOIN SmallTable
        WHERE BigTable.ID = SmallTable.ID
        AND BigTable.VALUATION_DATE IN 
                (SELECT MAX(VALUATION_DATE)
                FROM BigTable)
       GROUP BY BigTable.ID
```

/* My code: (I placed a WHERE in the inner query) */

```
SELECT BigTable.ID, SUM(BigTable.VALUE)
        FROM BigTable INNER JOIN SmallTable
        WHERE BigTable.ID = SmallTable.ID
        AND BigTable.VALUATION_DATE IN 
                (SELECT MAX(VALUATION_DATE)
                FROM BigTable INNER JOIN SmallTable
                    WHERE BigTable.ID = SmallTable.ID)
       GROUP BY BigTable.ID
```

If ID xyz has three accounts with values $1, $2, $3 respectively on the most recent date, I want to return the sum of all accounts on that date: xyz, $6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the [INNER JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) syntax you are using I believe is **incorrect**. After the INNER JOIN table that will be joined, **you need to state ON what columns you wish to join the tables on.**

The following query is the **correct** syntax (although it may not be correct for your implementation).

```
SELECT BigTable.ID, SUM(BigTable.VALUE)
        FROM BigTable INNER JOIN SmallTable
        ON BigTable.ID = SmallTable.ID
        WHERE BigTable.VALUATION_DATE IN 
                (SELECT MAX(VALUATION_DATE)
                FROM BigTable INNER JOIN SmallTable
                    ON BigTable.ID = SmallTable.ID)
       GROUP BY BigTable.ID
```

Only when you are doing **cross joins**, and **natural joins** do you not use the ON keyword and only use the WHERE command.

Comment: You forgot the `NATURAL JOIN`. It has no `ON` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid the where clause  and use the ON Clause

```
SELECT SUM(BigTable.VALUE)
FROM BigTable 
INNER JOIN SmallTable ON  BigTable.ID = SmallTable.ID
AND BigTable.VALUATION_DATE =  (
    SELECT MAX(VALUATION_DATE)
    FROM BigTable)
```

and youn should not use a group by id  ..

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions:

```
SELECT b.ID, b.VALUE
FROM (SELECT b.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b.id ORDER BY b.VALUATION_DATE DESC) as seqnum
      FROM BigTable b
     ) b JOIN
     SmallTable s
     ON b.ID = s.ID
WHERE b.seqnum = 1;
```

I don't think aggregation is necessary.  But, if you have multiple values on the same date for the same id, then:

```
SELECT b.ID, SUM(b.VALUE)
FROM (SELECT b.*,
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY b.id ORDER BY b.VALUATION_DATE DESC) as seqnum
      FROM BigTable b
     ) b JOIN
     SmallTable s
     ON b.ID = s.ID
WHERE b.seqnum = 1
GROUP BY b.id;
```